# Vue.js build the links in the built file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made my website in Vue.js because I found the dynamics easier and I would like to improve my knowledge. However, when I started to set up the SEO strategy, I started to encounter some difficulties.

Then I found the plugin "prerender-spa-plugin", "vue-tag-manager" and "vue-meta" that saved my life for almost everything. Now when I run the "npm run build" it generates my html site with the following structure of the image below:
[image]

However I did not find how to make it generate the link in the final file, because my sidebar:

```
<li
            id="menu-item-23731"
            @click="hoverLi = true"
            @mouseover="hoverLi = true"
            @mouseleave="hoverLi = false"
            class="li-master icon-solucoes menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children mouse-open"
          >
            <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Solucoes' })">
              <span>Soluções</span>
              <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" v-show="hoverLi == true">
              <li
                id="menu-item-281"
                class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"
              >
                <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Solucoes' })"
                  >Visão geral</a
                >
              </li>
              <li
                id="menu-item-282"
                class="icon-gold menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes"
              >
                <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Gold' })"
                  >Gold - Omnichannel</a
                >
              </li>
              <li
                id="menu-item-43822"
                class="icon-opal menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes"
              >
                <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Opal' })">Opal - WMS</a>
              </li>
              <li
                id="menu-item-43821"
                class="icon-jade menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes"
              >
                <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Jade' })">Jade - LiMS</a>
              </li>
              <li
                id="menu-item-282"
                class="icon-quartz menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes"
              >
                <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Quartz' })"
                  >Quartz - AMS</a
                >
              </li>
              <li
                id="menu-item-23861"
                class="fas fa-wifi menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"
              >
                <a>Módulos IoT</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li
                    id="menu-item-288"
                    class="icon-garnet menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes"
                  >
                    <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Garnet' })"
                      >Garnet - Beacons</a
                    >
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

in the final file it looks like this, without the links:

```
<li id="menu-item-23731"
                                              class="li-master icon-solucoes menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children mouse-open">
                                              <a><span>Soluções</span><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i><i
                                                        class="icon-arrow-right"></i><i
                                                        class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                                              <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                                   <li id="menu-item-281"
                                                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                                        <a>Visão geral</a></li>
                                                   <li id="menu-item-282"
                                                        class="icon-gold menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes">
                                                        <a>Gold - Omnichannel</a></li>
                                                   <li id="menu-item-43822"
                                                        class="icon-opal menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes">
                                                        <a>Opal - WMS</a></li>
                                                   <li id="menu-item-43821"
                                                        class="icon-jade menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes">
                                                        <a>Jade - LiMS</a></li>
                                                   <li id="menu-item-282"
                                                        class="icon-quartz menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes">
                                                        <a>Quartz - AMS</a></li>
                                                   <li id="menu-item-23861"
                                                        class="fas fa-wifi menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
                                                        <a>Módulos IoT</a>
                                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                             <li id="menu-item-288"
                                                                  class="icon-garnet menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-solucoes">
                                                                  <a>Garnet - Beacons</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                   </li>
                                              </ul>
                                         </li>
```

It works because the runtime javascript understands that when the user clicks on the link it is to go to the indicated route. However for my SEO tools they are not able to track the other pages of the site:
[image]

Does anyone know how to make vue.js generate the link in the final .html? Thank you so much community.

Comment: Hi, could you format it a bit better ? The code is not really readable as of right now. Hence, I don't even understand what is not generated right now. PS: you could check that your website is generating what you're expecting by checking it's source code (`ctrl + U` on your page) or disable the JS.

Comment: The reason why it is not generating the link is because you did not provide the `href` in your `<a>` tag. so i bet if you can use `<router-link>` everything will work fine.

Comment: True, `@click` events listeners will not generate anything because they are not able to generate any path at all, they are waiting you to click on them to bring you on the specific page.